# Creating a Rotating Partner, Round Robin Schedule

Tags: combinatorics

First, I'm going to apologize for a lack of proper terminology on this post.  It's been well over a decade since my days in the classroom, so I've regressed back to a simple math layman here.  (As a result, please add any missing/correct any inaccurate tags as needed)

The problem in a nutshell is to come up with a "perfect" rotating-partner/round-robin schedule that will allow for every person to *partner with every other participant in the tournament **once*** and *play against every other participant in the tournament **twice***.  The current bounds of the problem are that the number of players in the tournament (*n*) must be divisible by 4, and the total number of rounds played will be equal to *n-1*.

Take for example 4 players: the *perfect* schedule could be represented as follows:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    & T^1 (P^1) & T^1 (P^2) & vs & T^2 (P^1) & T^2 (P^2)\\  \hline
    Round\ 1 & A & B & & C & D\\ \hline
    Round\ 2 & A & C & & B & D\\ \hline
    Round\ 3 & A & D & & C & B\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

**Note:** $T^1(P^1)$ indicates Team 1 (Player 1)

This *solution* shows that all players partner with every other player once and play against them twice.

Upon using the brute-force method of identifying the next step, I've also been able to identify what the *perfect* schedule looks like for 8 players, as follows:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} \hline
    & T^1 (P^1) & T^1 (P^2) & v & T^2 (P^1) & T^2 (P^2) & & T^3 (P^1) & T^3 (P^2) & v & T^4 (P^1) & T^4 (P^2)\\ \hline
    Rnd\ 1 & A & B & & C & D & & E & F & & G & H\\ \hline
    Rnd\ 2 & A & C & & E & G & & B & D & & F & H\\ \hline
    Rnd\ 3 & A & D & & H & E & & B & C & & G & F\\ \hline
    Rnd\ 4 & A & E & & B & F & & C & G & & D & H\\ \hline
    Rnd\ 5 & A & F & & D & G & & C & H & & B & E\\ \hline
    Rnd\ 6 & A & G & & B & H & & C & E & & D & F\\ \hline
    Rnd\ 7 & A & H & & C & F & & D & E & & B & G\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

I'm quite confident there is a "perfect" solution for every iteration of this problem (e.g. 12, 16, 20 participants and higher), but as you continue to increase the number of players it becomes significantly less efficient to use the brute force method to identify what these schedules look like.

Has anyone tackled this problem before and come up with an elegant solution as opposed to using the brute force method?  If not, does anyone have any ideas on potential solutions or some methods I can look into to help identify a more efficient solution to solving this problem?

Comment: There's a generator for this type of tournament [here](http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/round-robin/rounds.php?it=12&v=w1). The site also has a message board where you can ask questions. Good luck!

Comment: @Jens that's terrific!  That link also shows this is called a Whist Tournament Schedule.  Now to do some more reading, but as far as I'm concerned this is the answer.  Feel free to post it formally and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a generator for this type of tournament [here](http://www.devenezia.com/downloads/round-robin/rounds.php?it=12&v=w1). The site also has a message board where you can ask questions. The site also links to [this](http://www.durangobill.com/BridgeCyclicSolutions.html) page where additional info on the underlying algorithms are given.